# Query upcoming birthdays

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

I'd like to query my customers for the ones, whose birthdays are yet to come.

I've tried this query, and it - of course - has failed breathtakingly:

```
Addresses.Where(adr => adr.DateOfBirth != null && adr.DateOfBirth.Value >
DateTime.Now).Take(15).ToList();
```

Of course this can't work properly (not if you're born in the future) and I'd like to know how I can query my `Nullable<DateTime>` without a year?

Comment: Given that *everyone* alive has an upcoming birthday at some point, how far do you want it to go? A month? End of the year?

Comment: `Take(15)` - just the next 15 birthdays. End of the year might be a problem when I run the query on December 31st

Comment: @Kamil That would also fail on December 31st when someone has his birthday on January 1st

Comment: @SeToY I realized that and deleted my comment.

Comment: @JonSkeet i think he wants next 15 birthdays, no matter "how far" are they.

Comment: @SeToY: In that case you're not really interested in a filter - you're interested in a sort order.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Bingo. First a list ordered by birth month and day, then just take the first 15.

Comment: @SeToY can you clarify on how many days or month the upcoming birthday?

Comment: @JonSkeet Well yeah, kinda. I don't want to filter anything, I just want to give out a list that contains the next 15 birthdays that are ahead

Comment: Whats wrong with you guys? :) 2 wrong answers are upvoted, one correct answer has no votes...

Comment: There seems to be a fundamental requirements question here.  Is this a query for people who have not been born?  Or is this a query for currently living people who's birthday for this year may have already passed?  I'm taking the latter interpretation, @Kamil seems to be taking the former.

Comment: @Kamil You are talking about your answer, eh? :D Cmon guys, give some love to my answer also.

Comment: @SeToY: fyi: please check my last update which I have tested with some of my data. I think that is much optimised.

Comment: @ThatBlairGuy The latter interpretation is the requirement

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it in one line like this:

```
context.Addresses.Where(adr => adr.DateOfBirth != null).OrderBy(adr => EntityFunctions.DiffDays(DateTime.Today, EntityFunctions.AddYears(adr.DateOfBirth, EntityFunctions.DiffYears(adr.DateOfBirth, DateTime.Today) + ((adr.DateOfBirth.Month < DateTime.Today.Month || (adr.DateOfBirth.Day <= DateTime.Today.Day && adr.DateOfBirth.Month == DateTime.Today.Month)) ? 1 : 0)))).Take(15).ToList();
```

Or in a more readable format:

```
var query = from adr in context.Addresses
            where adr.DateOfBirth != null
            let diffYears = EntityFunctions.DiffYears(adr.DateOfBirth, DateTime.Today)
            let birthdayOccurred = adr.DateOfBirth.Month < DateTime.Today.Month || (adr.DateOfBirth.Day <= DateTime.Today.Day && adr.DateOfBirth.Month == DateTime.Today.Month)
            let nextBirthdate = EntityFunctions.AddYears(adr.DateOfBirth, diffYears + (birthdayOccurred ? 1 : 0))
            let daysToBirthdate = EntityFunctions.DiffDays(DateTime.Today, nextBirthdate)
            orderby daysToBirthdate
            select adr;

var result = query.Take(15).ToList();
```

Comment: @SeToY Can you try running idea from my answer on your dataset - I think it will outperform this answer.

Comment: @kape123 I'll surely do, didn't see it yet. Will give it a try tomorrow and come back to ya!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can do this as a one-liner.  Certainly not with any degree of clarity.

The needed steps are:

1. Create an ordered list containing only the birthdates where the
   month/day comes after today.
2. Create an ordered list containing only the birthdates where the month/day is before today.
3. Append the second list to the first one, you now have a single list, sorted in
   birthday order.
4. Take the first 15.

I think the C# code would look something like this (You might need to add a List or two.)

```
var list1 = Addresses.Where(adr => adr.DateOfBirth != null && (adr.DateOfBirth.Value.Month > DateTime.Today.Month || (adr.DateOfBirth.Value.Month == DateTime.Today.Month && adr.DateOfBirth.Value.Day >= DateTime.Today.Day))).ToList();
var list2 = Addresses.Where(adr => adr.DateOfBirth != null && (adr.DateOfBirth.Value.Month < DateTime.Today.Month || (adr.DateOfBirth.Value.Month == DateTime.Today.Month && adr.DateOfBirth.Value.Day < DateTime.Today.Day))).ToList();
var fullList = list1.Add(list2);
```

Comment: You cant create lists of birthdates before and after today. First reason: at 31 December your list of greater dates will be empty. When someone have birthday 1 January - he will be next person with birthdays, but you wont see this.

Comment: I'm assuming his list is people who've already been born (otherwise they can't be customers yet).  The first list is people whose birthday is today or later.  The second list is people whose birthdays have already passed. By combining them like this, I've created a list of the next year's worth of birthdays.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this; (this is working - I've tested)

```
//A mock up value for comparison (as DayOfYear not supported in Linq)
int doy = DateTime.Today.Month * 31 + DateTime.Today.Day;

var results = Addresses.Where(a => a.DateOfBirth != null)
             .OrderBy( a => 
             (a.DateOfBirth.Value.Month * 31 + a.DateOfBirth.Value.Day) +
  (a.DateOfBirth.Value.Month * 31 + a.DateOfBirth.Value.Day > doy ? 0 : 400 ))
             .Take(15).ToList();
```

Comment: This is wrong. When current date is 8th January - it will not return row with 7th February (which is later date) because 7 is not greater than 8 (today).

Comment: I think that is still wrong. It will return data when any part of date is greater. Lets say we have now 2013-02-27. What if birthday is 2013-01-28? Your code will return that day, because 28 is greater than 27. You have to combine month and day, maybe like this: `int mmdd = month*100+day`, then compare. Alternatively something like DayOfYear may be used, but only combined with year.

Comment: After last edit your code will not work when "today" will be 31 December, and birthday will be 1 January next year.

Comment: This will still miss January birthdays when run in December

Comment: @msmucker0527: What dates should this be filtering out (not selected) if this runs in Dec?

Comment: It should pull the 15 upcoming birthdays regardless of when it's run, so on Dec. 31st 2013 the next birthday might be Jan 2nd 2014, with this query Jan 2nd would be eliminated

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with Linq, I'll try to help with some pseudocode.

Most important condition should look like this:

```
Date(CurrentDate.Year, DateOfBirth.Month, DateOfBirth.Day) >= CurrentDate 
|| ' OR
Date(CurrentDate.Year + 1, DateOfBirth.Month, DateOfBirth.Day) >= CurrentDate
```

This will work 31 December too.

Alternative:

```
// consider this as pseudocode, I didnt tested that in C#

function GetNextBirthday(DateTime DateOfBirth)
{
int yearOfNextBirthday;

int birthdayMMDD = DateOfBirth.Month*100 + DateOfBirth.Day;
int todayMMDD = CurrentDate.Month*100 + CurrentDate.Day;

    if (birthdayMMDD >= todayMMDD)
    {
        yearOfNextBirthday = CurrentDate.Year; // this year
    }
    else
    {
        yearOfNextBirthday = CurrentDate.Year + 1; // next year
    }

DateTime nextBirthday; 

// you have to write this line yourself, i dont remember how to make date from Y, M, D
nextBirthday = DateFromYMD(yearOfNextBirthday, DateOfBirth.Month, DateOfBirth.Day);

return nextBirthday;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my entry for "one liner":

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
var next15 =
    from a in db.Addresses
    where a.DateOfBirth != null
    let diff = EntityFunctions.DiffSeconds(
        EntityFunctions.AddYears(now, -EntityFunctions.DiffYears(a.DateOfBirth, now)),
        a.DateOfBirth)
    orderby diff >= 0 ? diff : diff + 366*24*60*60
    select new a;

var res = next15.Take(15).ToList();
```

Just tested with SQL Database - and it works like charm ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the same solution as @Aducci but with nullable date and the DBFunctions, as EntityFunctions became deprecated.

```
          pacientes = from paciente in pacientes
                where paciente.Nascimento != null
                let diffYears = DbFunctions.DiffYears(paciente.Nascimento, DateTime.Today)
                let birthdayOccurred = paciente.Nascimento.Value.Month < DateTime.Today.Month 
                || (paciente.Nascimento.Value.Day <= DateTime.Today.Day && paciente.Nascimento.Value.Month == DateTime.Today.Month)
                let nextBirthdate = DbFunctions.AddYears(paciente.Nascimento, diffYears + (birthdayOccurred ? 1 : 0))
                let daysToBirthdate = DbFunctions.DiffDays(DateTime.Today, nextBirthdate)
                orderby daysToBirthdate
                select paciente;
```