# Order the dates by upcoming birthdays in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I want to show upcoming birthdays in grid. I have list of values with random order and I want to get the order the dates from today's date (assume current date is *March 1st*) using LINQ.

```
List<DateTime> dtlist = new List<DateTime>();
```

```
List 1 value = "25-July-1985"
List 2 value = "31-Dec-1956"       
List 3 value = "21-Feb-1978"
List 4 value = "18-Mar-2005"
```

Output order should be:

```
18-Mar
25-July
31-Dec
21-Feb
```

Note: I am not using any DB over here to get values.

Comment: Here is your answer buddy: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118968/query-upcoming-birthdays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118968/query-upcoming-birthdays) [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/0c93a629-ec1d-4959-88b1-9aa0e73a9367](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/0c93a629-ec1d-4959-88b1-9aa0e73a9367)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that we cannot just project all dates to a date with the current year, because of (for example) leap days. Making `February 29th, 2000` into `February 29th, 2013` would be wrong.

Let's first order the dates by only their month and day:

```
var ordered = from dt in dtlist
              orderby dt.Month, dt.Day
              select dt;
```

Now we need to find all dates that are before the current date (regardless of year):

```
private static bool IsBeforeNow(DateTime now, DateTime dateTime)
{
    return dateTime.Month < now.Month
        || (dateTime.Month == now.Month && dateTime.Day < now.Day);
}
```

My original suggestion was to skip/take the dates we want and concatenate them together:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var afterNow = ordered.SkipWhile(dt => IsBeforeNow(now, dt));
var beforeNow = ordered.TakeWhile(dt => IsBeforeNow(now, dt));

var birthdays = Enumerable.Concat(afterNow, beforeNow);
```

However, user Rawling correctly [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159832/order-the-dates-by-upcoming-birthdays-in-linq/15160271#comment21348046_15160271) that this code will order your list of dates *twice*: once when `afterNow` is evaluated, and once when `beforeNow` is evaluated. His suggestion to order the dates by `IsBeforeNow` is even more elegant, because it removes the need to skip/take and concat. The previous code block is no longer necessary and the LINQ query part then becomes:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var birthdays = from dt in dtlist
                orderby IsBeforeNow(now, dt), dt.Month, dt.Day
                select dt;
```

And `birthdays` is your result. That has been incorporated in the code below:

---

The full code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dtlist = new[]{
        DateTime.Parse("25-July-1985"),
        DateTime.Parse("31-Dec-1956"),
        DateTime.Parse("21-Feb-1978"),
        DateTime.Parse("18-Mar-2005")
    };

    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var birthdays = from dt in dtlist
                    orderby IsBeforeNow(now, dt), dt.Month, dt.Day
                    select dt;

    foreach (var dt in birthdays)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd-MMM"));
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static bool IsBeforeNow(DateTime now, DateTime dateTime)
{
    return dateTime.Month < now.Month
        || (dateTime.Month == now.Month && dateTime.Day < now.Day);
}
```

Prints:

```
18-mrt
25-jul
31-dec
21-feb
```

Comment: Rather than sorting and then skipwhile/takewhile (which performs the sort twice), you could `OrderBy(IsBeforeNow).ThenBy(actual date)`... But otherwise, very nice :)

Comment: I like this better than my answer.  I tip my hat to you, sir.

Comment: Since people whose birthday is February 29th celebrate their birthday on March 1st it is better to use `DayOfYear` in your `IsBeforeNow` method. As a positive side effect this will slightly improve performance and can be inlined.

Answer (score 2):

```
//A mock up value for comparison (as DayOfYear has a leap year issue)
int doy = DateTime.Today.Month*31 + DateTime.Today.Day;

var results = dtlist.OrderBy( a => 
              (a.DateOfBirth.Month * 31 + a.DateOfBirth.Day) +
              (a.DateOfBirth.Month * 31 + a.DateOfBirth.Day > doy ? 0 : 400 ))
             .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This custom comparer delegate in [`List.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s.aspx) works:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
dtlist.Sort((d1, d2) =>
    {
        if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(d1.Year) && d1.Month == 2 && d1.Day == 29)
            d1 = d1.Date.AddMilliseconds(-1);
        if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(d2.Year) && d2.Month == 2 && d2.Day == 29)
            d2 = d2.Date.AddMilliseconds(-1);
        var dtTrunc1 = new DateTime(now.Year, d1.Month, d1.Day, d1.Hour, d1.Minute, d1.Second, d1.Millisecond);
        var dtTrunc2 = new DateTime(now.Year, d2.Month, d2.Day, d2.Hour, d2.Minute, d2.Second, d2.Millisecond);
        TimeSpan diff1 = dtTrunc1 - now;
        TimeSpan diff2 = dtTrunc2 - now;
        if (diff1.Ticks >= 0 && diff2.Ticks >= 0 || diff1.Ticks < 0 && diff2.Ticks < 0)
            return diff1.Ticks.CompareTo(diff2.Ticks);
        else if (diff1.Ticks < 0 && diff2.Ticks >= 0)
            return int.MaxValue;
        else
            return int.MinValue;
    });
```

[**1. Demo**](http://ideone.com/guWCge) ( your sample data )

[**2. Demo**](http://ideone.com/iKQc1C) ( >1000 random dates to demonstrate that it's working, including leap years )

This approach doesn't need to create a new list, it sorts the original list. It also orders by time if the `DateTime` variable also contains it.

Comment: Leap year bug, I think - would attempt to construct 29 Feb 2013 given the right input data.

Comment: @AakashM: Good catch, i have edited the answer. The second demo includes now a leap year.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for any range and all cases:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<DateTime> birthdays = new List<DateTime>() {
            new DateTime(1977,1,29),
            new DateTime(1977,1,30),
            new DateTime(1977,1,31)
            };

            var daysFrom = 30;
            var start = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,DateTime.Now.Month,DateTime.Now.Day);
            start = new DateTime(2020, 12, 31); // border test case
            var last = start.AddDays(daysFrom);
            var yearSwitch = last.Year - start.Year;
            var res = birthdays.Where(bday =>
                {
                    var bn = new DateTime(start.Year, bday.Month, bday.Day);
                    if (bday.DayOfYear < daysFrom)
                    {
                        bn = bn.AddYears(yearSwitch);
                    }
                    return bn >= start && bn <= last;
                }
            ).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine("List:{0}", string.Join(",", res));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem with a number of ways to make an error! Here's my attempt:

- For each birth **date**, calculate when the next birth **day** is - This is defined as the first of the birthdays (the days obtained by successively adding a year to the birthdate) that is on or after today
- Order the next birth **days** in ascending order
- Return the list

Sample code:

```
var dtlist  = new[]{
    DateTime.Parse("25-July-1985"),
    DateTime.Parse("31-Dec-1956"),
    DateTime.Parse("21-Feb-1978"),
    DateTime.Parse("18-Mar-2005")
};

var today = DateTime.Today;

var nextbirthDays = 
    from birthdate in dtlist
    select 
        Enumerable.Range(0, 1000)
        .Select(birthdate.AddYears)
        .First(birthday => birthday >= today);

var ordered = 
    nextBirthdays
    .OrderBy(d => d)
    .ToList();
```

Note that this returns the full `DateTime`s of the upcoming birthdays, which you can format as `dd-MMM` as required. Note also that before .NET 4.0, you would need

```
.Select(age => birthdate.AddYears(age))
```

instead of

```
.Select(birthdate.AddYears)
```

Answer (score 0):

Others stated that `DayOfYear` has a `leap year issue`. Actually I can't find any issue: February 29th has `DayOfYear == 60` and March 1st has `DayOfYear == 60` in a non-leap year and `DayOfYear == 61` in a leap year, both is correct. So you can use `DayOfYear` for filtering but you can not use it for sorting since this would mix up February 29th with March 1st, March 1st with March 2nd etc. But it's ok to just order by month and day:

```
var upcomingBirthdays = birthdays.Where(dt => dt.DayOfYear >= DateTime.Today.DayOfYear).OrderBy(dt => dt.Month).ThenBy(dt => dt.Day);
```

or

```
var upcomingBirthdays = from birthday in birthdays
                        where birthday.DayOfYear >= DateTime.Today.DayOfYear
                        orderby birthday.Month, birthday.Day
                        select birthday;
```

If somebody's birthday is February 29th it will come up on March 1st in a non-leap year and it will come up on just that day in a leap year. This is how I would expect it in a birthday calendar.

**Update:**

There is still one issue with my implementation: It won't show up upcoming birthdays for the next year.

Since the missing birthdays happen to be the rest of the original list you can just do the same for them and then concat the results:

```
var thisYear = from birthday in birthdays
               where birthday.DayOfYear >= DateTime.Today.DayOfYear
               orderby birthday.Month, birthday.Day
               select birthday;

var nextYear = from birthday in birthdays
               where birthday.DayOfYear < DateTime.Today.DayOfYear
               orderby birthday.Month, birthday.Day
               select birthday;

var upcomingBirthdays = thisYear.Concat(nextYear);
```

This way the result always contains all entries of the original list in the order of upcoming birthdays.

Comment: It looks like the list is sorted twice here but it isn't. It seems that there is a lot of optimization going on due to deferred execution. Surprisingly for large lists this implementation is even slightly faster than Virtlinks's solution which is however more elegant.

Comment: I agree with your reasoning about leap years **provided that** it's true that (as you say elsewhere) "people whose birthday is February 29th celebrate their birthday on March 1st [in a non-leap year]". Is it? I bet some celebrate on Feb 28. In any case, it's an interesting yet *another* thing to consider!

Comment: @AakashM: I did a quick search for this: On a german webpage parents of leap year babys have been asked when their children celebrate. [70% said it is March 1st](http://www.eltern.de/familie-und-urlaub/familienleben/schaltjahr-geburtstag.html) (click on "Ergebnis"). According to [11 Random Facts About Leap Day](http://www.11points.com/Misc/11_Random_Facts_About_Leap_Day) those people dont't hit legal milestones (drinking age, smoking age etc.) in the UK or Hong Kong and most US states before March 1st. But in places like China, Taiwan and New Zealand February 28th is the legal birthday.

Answer (score -1):

```
var currentYear = DateTime.Today.Year;
var birthDays = dtList.Select(d => Tuple.Create(d, new DateTime(currentYear, d.Month, d.Day)))
    .OrderBy(tuple => tuple.Item2)
    .Where(tuple => tuple.Item2 > DateTime.Today)
    .Select(tuple => tuple.Item1)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Won't return `21-Feb-1978`, I think.

Comment: @AakashM, well, that's because today is March 1.

Comment: But look at the question. `21 Feb` is desired in the output.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you will be able to do this with your collection of dates as they are.  The trick is that the birthdates are all specific dates in the past but you want to be able to figure when that date will recur in the coming year.  This means you will need to first convert each birthdate (e.g. 25-July-**1985**) to the next occurrence of that month/day combination (e.g.25-July-**2013**).  Only then will the OrderBy mentioned in the other answers work.

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> UpcomingBirthdays(IEnumerable<DateTime> birthDates)
{
    return birthDates.Select(
        bd => new DateTime( 
            ((bd.Month >= DateTime.Today.Month || (bd.Month == DateTime.Today.Month && bd.Day >= DateTime.Today.Day)) ? DateTime.Today.Year : DateTime.Today.Year + 1),
            bd.Month,
            bd.Day)
        ).OrderBy(bd => bd);
}
```

This method determines when each birthday will occur next then orders *those* dates.

Comment: And how do you deal with leap years? E.g. `Feb 29th, 2000` should become... `Feb 29th, 2016` but your code does not do that.

Comment: True, my code doesn't handle leap years, but I don't think jumping to 2016 is an appropriate response.  That person still celebrates a birthday in 2013.

Comment: @Virtlink or rather, in some circumstances this code will attempt to make a `DateTime` for 29 Feb in a non leap year, and fall over.